# Getting bad address when I fork?

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory

So I have three files: `Pellets.c`, `Fish.c`, and `SwimMill.c`. SwimMill calls Pellets and Fish, which should fork. However, when I try to fork Pellets, i get an error saying "Pellet fork failed: Bad Address". Anyone know what the problem is?

include.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define SHM_SIZE 1000

int shmid;
int *shm;
pid_t fish;
pid_t pellet;


void attachSharedMemory() {
  key_t key = ftok("SwimMill.c", 'b'); //generate random key
  shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT|0666);
  shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

}
```

SwimMill.c

```
// Uses both fish and pellets, 30 seconds, then print it out
// Create pellets at random intervals, from 0x80
// Eating --> Get rid of most significant bit
// Use shared memory for fish and pellet position only
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "include.h"

#define SHM_SIZE 1000

void printGrid(int*);
void handler(int);
void killProgram(pid_t, pid_t, int*, int);
pid_t fish;
pid_t pellet;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int timer = 0;
    attachSharedMemory(); // from include.h
    signal(SIGINT, handler);


    // Initializing the shared memory to prevent segmentation fault
    // for (int i = 0; i < SHM_SIZE; i++){
    //  shm[i] = -1;
    // }
    srand(time(NULL));
    fish = fork();

    if (fish == -1) {
        perror("Fish fork failed1");
        exit(1);
    }   else if (fish == 0) {
        execv("Fish", argv);
        perror("Fish exec failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(timer <= 30){
        pellet = fork();
        if (pellet == -1) {
            perror("Pellet Fork failed1");
            exit(1);
        }   else if (pellet == 0) {
            execv("Pellets", argv);
            perror("Pellets Fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        printGrid(shm);
        sleep(1);
        printf("Timer: %d\n", timer);
        timer++;
    }

    killProgram(fish, pellet, shm, shmid);
    getchar(); // Pause consol
    return 0;
}


void printGrid(int* shm) {
    int row = 10;
    int column = 10;
    char (*stream)[row][column]; //2D Dimensional array, fish can only move last row of 2d

    //Initializing grid first
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            (*stream)[i][j] = '~';
        }
    }
    printf("Fish: %d \n", shm[0]);
    printf("Shm2 is: %d \n", shm[1] );
    for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++) {
        (*stream)[shm[k]/10][shm[k]%10] = 'O'; // pellets
    }
    (*stream)[shm[0]/10][shm[0]%10] = 'Y'; // Fish
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            printf("%c ", (*stream)[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

void killProgram(pid_t fish, pid_t pellet, int *shm, int shmid) {
    kill(fish,SIGUSR1);
    kill(pellet, SIGUSR1);
    sleep(5);
    shmdt(shm);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    printf("Program finished! \n");
}

void handler(int num ) {
    kill(fish,SIGUSR1);
    kill(pellet, SIGUSR1);
    shmdt(shm);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    perror(" Interrupt signal is pressed!! \n");

    exit(1);
}
```

Pellets.c

```
// Multiple pellets
//Process ID, position, eaten/misse
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "include.h"

#define SHM_SIZE 1000

void handler(int);
void eatPellet();
void missPellet();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  signal(SIGINT, handler);

  attachSharedMemory();
  srand(time(NULL));

  int i = 1; // 1 - 19 are pellets
  for (; i < 20; i++) {
    int pelletPosition = rand() % 9 ; // random number from 0 - 9
    if (shm[i] == -1){
      // printf("hello %d \n", pelletPosition);
      shm[i] = pelletPosition;
    }
    break;
  }
  while(1) {
    printf("helloasd %d \n", shm[i]);
    printf("i: %d \n", i);
    if (shm[i] < 90) {
      shm[i] += 10;
    }
    else if (shm[i] == shm[0]) {
      eatPellet();
      printf("Position: %d\n", shm[i] );
      break;
      // EATEN and KILL
    }
    else {
      // KIll process, terminate
      missPellet();
      printf("Position: %d\n", shm[i] );
      break;
    }
    // printf("%d\n",shm[i] );
    i++;
    sleep(1);
  }
  shmdt(shm);
  return 0;
}

void handler(int num) {
    shmdt(shm);
    exit(1);
}
```

I looked at other stack overflow questions, and it seems that they problems because they didn't terminate with a NULL? I think the problem lies inside Pellets.c, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: You asked this question earlier (or a very similar one about bad address and fork) today; you've asked previous questions about SwimMill, Pellets and Fish.  What happened to the previous question?  Why are you asking anew now?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, am I not suppose to re-ask again if the other one didn't gain any traction? Still stuck on the same problem.

Comment: If the other got no traction, maybe you needed to improve it?  I looked at it and remembered seeing questions on this general set of files from a month or so ago, and decided I wasn't really ready to spend time on it.  I'm sorry if no-one else was interested either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I honestly tried to improve it better than the last time. Maybe I still have to trim the code even further? I do want to ask a better question.

Comment: If the error is "`Pellets Fork failed: bad address`", then the problem is that the `execvp()` failed (poor error reporting — change the name of the failed function in the error message to match the function that failed!), then "bad address" probably means you've done something with `argv` to break things, though it isn't immediately obvious what.  Anything which requires three programs to reproduce the issue probably isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: If you try e.g. `execl` instead, as in `execl("./Pellets", "Pellets", NULL);`, does it work? Or if you set up a new `argv`-like array in the child-process to pass to `execv`? Then the problem is most certainly related to the argument array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, I sort of understand. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The execl didn't work. Still getting bad address.

Comment: I literally took out argv, and argc from the main, and I am still getting bad address. Are you sure its the argv that's causing the bad address?

Comment: It is puzzling that you're getting 'bad address' from unmodified `argv`. Does this problem occur on the first cycle or after some time? There are only two addresses passed to `execvp()` — one is a string literal, the other is `argv`. The only alternative source of 'bad address' is the string literal, which is pretty improbable. I note that your quoted error message prefix doesn't appear exactly in the source code — I misread last night.  But `fork()` failing with 'bad address' is even less plausible. Silly question time: when did you last reboot? Has anything else been behaving erratically?

Comment: Can you explain why bad address occur in the first place? Is it because I'm using memory space that isn't supposed to be used? I'm running on virtual machine, and I already rebooted, but still getting the same error. The only problem I can think of is inside the `Pellets.c` file. Does bad address occur when `execv` is called, or can it occur inside the file it is being forked?

Comment: So I found out what's causing the problem, but I still have no idea why this happens. It lies in `(*stream)[i][j] = '~';`. Anybody can explain this occurring?

Comment: @Slay EBADADDR is a *socket error*. It does not mean invalid memory address.